# How to get the access_token for Facebook with no application

Tags: facebook, graph

On the [documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for Facebook Graph API there are a lot of example links such as https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=SOME_AT

Could anyone explain how the access_token for these links are generated?

All I've read in the documentation were about getting access_token only for applications, but on that page everyone could get an access_token without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the graph API to get public information. People set privacy settings on facebook, so to prevent social freaks from stalking you, they(fb) created Autorisation.What I believe is that on the documentation, they are generating the access token using the [Developers App](http://facebook.com/developers). You can generate this Access token by making an application and asking a user to Authorise your application to access his data using OAUTH dialogs. Usually people reading at developer.facebook.com have enabled the Developers app so it easily opens your information.

> The Graph API as such allows you to
>   easily access all public information
>   about an object. For example,
>   https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor
>   (Bret Taylor) returns all the public
>   information about Bret. For example a
>   user's first name, last name and
>   profile picture are publicly
>   available.

---

> To get additional information about a
>   user, you must first get their
>   permission. At a high level, you need
>   to get an access token for the
>   Facebook user. After you obtain the
>   access token for the user, you can
>   perform authorized requests on behalf
>   of that user by including the access
>   token in your Graph API requests:

---

Comment: And could I for example generate one using  Developers App? AFAIK to do this I need a secret key which is known only for the developers of the application.

Comment: Also Developers App asks me for the permissions, that means that I didn't get them to the application, but using access_token generated with Developers App anyone could retrieve my data. How is it possible?

Comment: No. You can't this is generated backend using PHP by Facebook. If it could be generated by hand it would be abused in so many ways. Earlier, when the GraphAPI was launched, a person used a script to get all the public information and store it in a database.

Comment: You can access all your information on facebook, can't you? So i think it is your own access token and therefore I can't see yours and you can't see mine using our access tokens

Answer (score 1):

The access_token in these links are generated using your Facebook identity and an application ID (presumable associated to "developers.facebook.com"). If you go to the same page with another Facebook account, you will see different access tokens.